# operação com vetores

Tags: python

Tenho duas variáveis **m1** e **m2** que mudam a cada conjunto de dados que importo e um vetor (medidas)com os valores, preciso ver se os valores do vetor são maiores que **M1** ou menores que o **M2** e exclui-los caso sejam. E lista-los para ver quais valores foram excluídos.**texto em negrito**

Answer (score 0):

o .split() ele "quebra" a string digitada por espaço que é o default, com isso o usuário digita 1 2 e m1 recebe o 1 e o m2 recebe o 2, porém elas são strings, ai uso o .map() para fazer a conversão dessas entradas para int e o .remove() pega um valor e retira ele da lista se a condição for atendida. Se você ainda não entendeu, dê uma pesquisada em Listas no python.

```
lista = [10,20,30]
excluidos = []
m1, m2 = map(int, input().split()) # convertendo os valores digitados para int
for n in lista:
    if n > m1 or n < m2:
            excluidos.append(n)
            lista.remove(n)
print(excluidos)
```